# How to maintain activity when user press the home button or back button without stop|exit|submit the activity 2

Tags: android

I have two activity (A, B):

A: Song Button
B(WebView): Song Play List - Embadded from URL

My question is, when user go to B to start play music and user back to A without stop the music (Music is playing in B)...but when user go to B again the WebView in B is new while the old B is still playing the music. So, how can allow user can go to old B to stop music?

I really stuck on this over a week :((

I do appreciate for your ur help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following flag on the intent

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

while creating activity B. For more information about this, check the link below 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: in B i added code under onCreat():<br />Intent myIntent = new Intent(B, A.class);<br />myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);<br />
startActivity(myIntent);<br /> it's not work :(